# Is it possible to have a fragment open and close like a navigation drawer

Tags: android

Like the question implies. I was wondering if i can have a fragment open and close on command like a navigation drawer.

Comment: Fragments don't open and close. Views open and close. Fragments might manage a view that opens and closes. Either use `DrawerLayout` itself or [read through the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/core-ui/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java) to learn how it handles the gestures, animations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `NavigationView` is a `ViewGroup` put a `Fragment` inside and you got it.

`<NavigatiomView>
    <fragment
    name...
    id.... />
</NavigatiomView>`

Just remember to remove the `header` and the `menu` attribute, you are not gonna use it anymore.

Comment: Ok thank you guys.i was wondering if this was possible  even though it did not seem possible for fragments to behave in such a way